# Disabling other domain users in openfire?

Tags: openfire

Is it possible to disable other domain users to add my domain users as friend in openfire? I mean I have a domain, say abc.org and I want only users with abc.org domain can add each other as friends. Someone who has a domain like jabber.org couldn't add a user who has a domain like abc.org as a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PrivacyList extension](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html) of XMPP. Though, i have no experience using this, however, it can suffice your objective to block certain domains.